# Writing an ArrayList back to an XML File

Tags: java, android

When my activity starts I check for an existing data file and if there isn't one I call a web service that provides a blank one to begin with. The file is read into an ArrayList collection and the user makes changes as needed. Now I am in need of advice for the best approach.

Should I try to match the updated contents in the ArrayList to the element in the XML file (there is an ID field that could be used for matching) or should I just write out the ArrayList overwriting the old xml file? No worries about maintaining a hx.

If I write out the file (what I'm thinking is the way to go) do I have to decorate everything in the DataObject class (ie all the properties) as serializable or just at the class level. Do I also somehow need to mark the ArrayList collection serializable as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to mark your `ArrayList` or `DataObject` as serializable if you just want to write it out as XML, check for e.g [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) for Basic Object to XML conversion.

Also since you are containing the whole content in your `ArrayList` which means at any given point in time your `ArrayList` contains the updated data, if you just override the XML file it will be much easier for coding point of view as you need not do any dirty check.